# Can't connect to domain VM Windows Server 2019 in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, domain, windows-server-2019

I created 3 VMs, 1 is AD domain VM Windows Server 2019, 1 is normal PC Windows 10, and the other is another Windows Server 2019.

I used to be able to connect in my last time trying, but this round I got stuck and do not know why.

Here is my configuration of the three VMs:

- The domain VM with Windows Server 2019:

  > [image]
- The VM of Windows Server 2019:

  > [image]
- The VM of Windows 10:

  > [image]
- The configuration of network for both 3 VMs is:

  > [image]

Why after I install AD to the domain VM the internet is blocked? And why can't I connect the Windows 10 VM and the other Windows Server VM to the IP address of the domain? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: DNS settings should ONLYbe the AD controller IP, your Win Server should point to the DC, not itself or the Win10 VM. And, same with Win10, DNS should be DC.  Also, IIRC, internal networking is VM to VM only, no external access.  You also need to set up DNS forwarding on your DC if you want external DNS resolution.